# Let H be a subgroup of G. Let $g_1,g_2\in G$. Prove that the following conditions are equivalent

Tags: group-theory

Let H be a subgroup of G. Let $g_1,g_2\in G$. Prove that the following conditions are equivalent:

i.$g_1H=g_2H$

ii.$Hg_1^{-1}=Hg_2^{-1}$

iii.$g_2\in g_1H$

iv.$g_1^{-1}g_2\in H$

This was a question given in a book. However, I am not been able to get how can we say that i. implies ii.. If $g_1H=g_2H$, then we can say for, $h_1,h_2\in H$, we have $g_1h_1=g_2h_2$ and hence,  $g_2=g_1h_1h_2^{-1}$. Now, $h=h_1h_2^{-1}\in H$ and thus, $g_2=g_1h$ . So, we can say $g_2\in g_1H$. Now, if $g_2=g_1h$, then $g_1^{-1}g_2=h\in H$. So, we can say that, $g_1^{-1}g_2=\in H$. Thus , we see that i.implies iii. and iii. implies iv.. But how to prove i. implies ii. ? Also then if we prove  i. implies ii. , then can we say ii. imples iii. since i. imples ii. ?  How to show that ii. implies iii. ? If we can show that i. implies ii. and ii. implies iii. , I think we can say that all the following conditions are equivalent, right? I think we dont need to show that ii. implies i. (which may not be the case also) as the question asks us to show that i,ii,iii,iv are equivalent .But how to prove it ? I am not quite getting it.

Comment: Which book are you referring to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(i) \to (iii)$: We have $g_1 H = g_2 H$ which implies that $g_1 h = g_2 \hat h$ for some $h,\hat h \in H$. Then we know that $g_1 h \hat h^{-1} = g_2$, which implies that $g_2 \in g_1H$.

$(iii) \to (iv)$: We have $g_2 = g_1 h$ for some $h \in H$. Hence $g_1^{-1} g_2 = h$ and so $g_1^{-1} g_2 \in H$.

$(iv) \to (ii)$: Note that $H = H (g^{-1}g_2)$ and so $H g_2^{-1} = H g_1^{-1}$.

$(ii) \to (i)$: We have $h g_1^{-1} = \hat h g_2^{-1} \implies g_1 h^{-1} = g_2 \hat h^{-1} \implies g_1 H = g_2H$.

Comment: But shouldn't we prove ii implies iii, also ?

Comment: Not sure, I understand why. Didn't we show equivalence $(i)\to(iii)\to(iv)\to(ii)\to(i)$?

Comment: I can prove i implies ii now, but I really don't get how to prove ii. imples i. ? Thank you!...

Answer (score 3):

$$g_{1}H=g_{2}H \implies  g_{1}=g_{1}e=g_{2}h \implies g_{1}^{-1}=h^{-1}g_{2}^{-1} $$
So $$\forall k\in H, kg_{1}^{-1}=kh^{-1}g_{2}^{-1}\implies Hg_{1}^{-1} \subset  Hg_{2}^{-1}$$
In the same way u can prove the reverse inclusion.

Comment: @belkam abderrahmane When we proved $g_1^{-1}\in Hg_2^{-1}$, we have $g_1^{-1}\in Hg_1^{-1}$. Now, we know that any two right cosets are either distinct or equal,  so we can directly conclude from there $Hg_1^{-1}=Hg_2^{-1}$. This can be a way , right? But then we need to show ii implies iii , to make it complete , right?